# ASP.NET MVC Url.Action in JQuery is not recognized

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use Url.Action() method in my js file to define urls for my ajax calls. So far I have failed.

```
 $.ajax(
 {
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")',
    data: { 
        fileID: rightClickedFileId
    },
    success: function (data) {

    }
 });
```

If i define the url in this way, browser tries to post data to

```
http://localhost:5907/FileManager/@Url.Action(%22SomeAction%22,%20%22SomeController%22)
```

and as a result my ajax call fails.

However, If I use `'/SomeController/SomeAction'` instead, everythings works fine.

Second works ok, but I am wondering the problem with first one ? Could it be due to routing configuration ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Url.Action` is an html helper method which will work in your razor view, not in your external javascript files.

What you can do is, get the relative url to your action method using `Url.Action` helper method in a razor view and set that to a javascript variable and use that in your external js file. When doing this, **Always make sure to use javascript namespacing** to avoid possible conflict with existing global variables.

You may add this code in the *_Layout.cshtml*

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var yourApp = yourApp || {};
    yourApp.Urls = yourApp.Urls || {};
    yourApp.Urls.baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~")';
    yourApp.Urls.editUserUrl= '@Url.Action("Edit","User")';

</script>
```

Or in your page specific view,

```
@section Scripts
{
  <script type="text/javascript">

     var yourApp = yourApp || {};
     yourApp.Urls = yourApp.Urls || {};
     yourApp.Urls.baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~")';
     yourApp.Urls.editUserUrl= '@Url.Action("Edit","User")';

  </script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/PageSpecificExternalJsFile.js"></script>    
}
```

Now in your external javascript file, you can access it like

```
var urlToEditUser = yourApp.Urls.editUserUrl;
//you can use urlToEditUser  now

// Or With the base url, you may safely add the remaining part of your url.
var urlToEditUser2 = yourApp.Urls.baseUrl+"User/Edit";
//you can use urlToEditUser2  now
```

Always use the `Url.Action` or `Url.RouteUrl` html helper methods to build the relative url to the action methods. It will take care of correctly building the url regardless of your current page/path.

If you want to do the same thing inside your angular controller's/data services etc, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34600407/40521) which explains how to use the angular value provider to do the same.

Comment: but is not writing js code to MVC view also a bad practice ? I

Comment: to get the Path to a global variable, It is fine. This is the only way you can get the path using the Helper method and pass to external js file.

Answer (score 7):

You can't use `'@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")'` in js file, because this is ASP.NET MVC helper, if you put your code to the view everything will work.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is similar to @Shyju's, except instead of setting one variable in the Razor view, I call an `init` function in my JavaScript, and pass it all the parameters that I need interpreted by Razor.

So the code would look like this:

```
MyScript.init({
    editUserUrl: "@Url.Action("Edit","User")",
    anotherUrl: "@Url.Action("AnotherUrl", "User")"
})
```

Then in JavaScript:

```
var m_options;
MyScript.init = function(options) {
    m_options = options;
}

// use with m_options.editUserUrl here
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: m_options.editUserUrl,
    data: { 
        fileID: rightClickedFileId
    },
    success: function (data) {
    }
 });
```

I wrote a more detailed post about it here:
http://blog.blanklabs.com/2015/02/aspnet-mvc-refactoring-friendly.html

Answer (score 1):

you can write it like this way  just

```
url:'/controllername/Actionname',
```