# Unable to access controller method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to call for a method that i have done on my controller. However i do not know why it kept giving me error and did not even enter the controller method.

```
public ActionResult retrieveBySelected(int exerciseRegionID, int exerciseTypeID)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("enter");
    ExerciseVideo exerciseVideo = new ExerciseVideo();
    List<Exercise> list = db.Exercises.ToList();
    foreach(Exercise e in list)
    {
        if (e.ExerciseTypeID == exerciseTypeID && e.ExerciseRegionID == exerciseRegionID)
        {
            exerciseVideo = db.ExerciseVideos.Where(m => m.ExerciseID == e.ExerciseID).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
    return Json(exerciseVideo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}


@section Scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script language="javascript">
    function selectList() {
        var exerRegion = document.getElementById("region");
        var exerType = document.getElementById("type");
        var exerRegionID = exerRegion.options[exerRegion.selectedIndex].value;
        var exerTypeID = exerType.options[exerType.selectedIndex].value;
        var variable = { exerciseRegionID: "exerRegionID", exerciseTypeID: "exerTypeID" };
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%= Url.Action("retrieveBySelected", "PublicModulesController") %>',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: variable,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.Result);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
}
```

Comment: Remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` (your not stringifying the data, and there is no need to)

Comment: Hi, i tried removing it before, however it does not seem to work.

Comment: Also your sending strings to a method that has 2 parameters which are both `int` - it should be `var variable = { exerciseRegionID: exerRegionID, exerciseTypeID: exerTypeID };` (no quotes)

Comment: remove content type just dataType is ok.

Comment: Or even better `var variable = { exerciseRegionID: $("#region").val(), exerciseTypeID: ("#type").val() };` and delete the 1st 4 lines of your script

Comment: yes @StephenMuecke is right. Make it simple.

Comment: Please check quotes in your code with mine     

    var variable = { "exerciseRegionID": $("#region").val(), "exerciseTypeID": $("#type").val() };

Comment: Thanks for all your help. However this is the error i encountered.
POST http://localhost:9765/PublicModules/%3C%=%20Url.Action(%22retrieveBySelected%22,%20%22PublicModulesController%22)%20%%3E

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Comment: Stop including links that cannot be navigated to. Show the actual `url` you generating. I suspect this is an external js file (razor code is not parsed in external files). But you still need to make the changes I noted above as well

Comment: Yes @StephenMuecke is right.It can be written in external js not cshtml.

Comment: If problem is external js then you should write code as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514745/asp-net-mvc-url-action-in-jquery-is-not-recognized?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: And do you seriously have a controller named `PublicModulesControllerController`?

Comment: Nope its just PublicModulesController. Not too sure what do you mean by external js file. Do you mean i imported the file into the project? I am really sorry but i am rather new to coding and is trying my best to understand how this work.

Comment: Show the output of `<%= Url.Action("retrieveBySelected", "PublicModules") %>` (note its `PublicModules` , not `PublicModulesController`) You have so many errors its hard to know where to start but let get the url correct first

Comment: Ok. It kept saying it is a bad request-Invalid URL. This is is the URL i retrieved.

PublicModules/<%=%20Url.Action("retrieveBySelected",%20"PublicModules")%20%>

Comment: Which means one of 2 things. (1) The script you have shown is in an external `.js` file or (2) Your actually using razor, not aspx so it should be `url: '@Url.Action("retrieveBySelected", "PublicModules")',` (and looking at your unformatted code - it appears to be No. 2)

Comment: You controller code makes no sense either. I will add a detailed answer shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple errors in your code

1. Your using the razor view engine, so it needs to be `@Url.Action()`,
   not `<%= Url.Action() %>`
2. Your controller is named `PublicModulesController`, not
   `PublicModulesControllerController`, so it needs to be
   `@Url.Action("retrieveBySelected", "PublicModules")`
3. You sending the text values "exerRegionID" and "exerTypeID" (not the
   value of your dropdownlists) to a controller method that expects
   `int`
4. Your not stringifying the data so you need to remove the
   `contentType` option (so it uses the default `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`)
5. The json your returning does not contain a property named `Result`

Your script should be

```
function selectList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("retrieveBySelected", "PublicModules")',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { exerciseRegionID: $("#region").val(), exerciseTypeID: $("#type").val() },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data); // 
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Its not clear what your attempting to return based on the code in your controller. Your loop just keeps overwriting any existing value of `exerciseVideo` that was assigned in previous iterations. But if your expecting that there will be only one match, then you should be getting only that item and avoiding all the unnecessary overhead of your current code. My best guess is you want to return the first `ExerciseVideo` where the TypeID and RegionID matches the values your selecting in the dropownlists, in which case its

```
public ActionResult retrieveBySelected(int exerciseRegionID, int exerciseTypeID)
{
    var data = db.ExerciseVideos.Where(x => x.ExerciseTypeID == exerciseTypeID && x.ExerciseRegionID == exerciseRegionID).FirstOrDefault();
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and is that is in fact correct, you don't want to send the `ExerciseVideo` object. What you want to return is an anonymous object containing only those properties of `ExerciseVideo` you need in the view (you just sent properties `ExerciseTypeID` and `ExerciseRegionID` to the controller, so there is no need to send them back again - you already know what they are in the view)

Alternatively, what you may want is

```
var exercise = db.Exercises.Where(x => x.ExerciseTypeID == exerciseTypeID && x.ExerciseRegionID == exerciseRegionID).FirstOrDefault();
var data = db.ExerciseVideos.Where(m => m.ExerciseID == e.ExerciseID).FirstOrDefault();
```

although is that's the case, a linq join statement may be easier

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be

```
<script language="javascript">
    function selectList() {            
        //simple jquery access 
        var exerRegionID = $("#region").val();           
        var exerTypeID = $("#exerRegionID").val();

        //change of quotes
        //var variable = { exerciseRegionID: "exerRegionID", exerciseTypeID: "exerTypeID" };
        var variable = { "exerciseRegionID": exerRegionID, "exerciseTypeID": exerTypeID };

        $.ajax({
            url: '<%= Url.Action("retrieveBySelected", "PublicModulesController") %>',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: variable,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.Result);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```