# ASP MVC Angular JS $http not found

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, http, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with calling http get to WebApi controller from my angular code. I am using ASP MVC just to provide start page and the start page url looks like: http://localhost:23845/StudentsEditor/StudentsView and now from angular I am callinh http request:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "api/Groups/GetGroups",
            dataType: "json",
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.groups = response.data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            alert("trouble...");
        });
```

and I am getting 404 because the URL is incorrect. It concats the path and it loks like:
GET http://localhost:23845/StudentsEditor/api/Groups/GetGroups
instead of http://localhost:23845/api/Groups/GetGroups

plese give me some advice hoe to resolve it. Of course I have defined RouteConfig:
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "StudentsEditor", action = "StudentsView", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

and the webApi config:

```
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{url}/api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not hard code url's like that. You may use the `Url.Content` or `Url.RouteUrl` helper methods in your razor view to generate the relative url to the app base/root. It will take care of correctly building the url regardless of your current page/path. Once you get this value, You can use angular's `value` provider to pass this data from your razor view to your angular controller/ angular data services.

So in your razor view (Specific page/ Layout file), You may add this.

```
<script>
    var myApp = myApp || {};
    myApp.Urls = myApp.Urls || {};
    myApp.Urls.baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~")';       
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/AngularControllerForPage.js"></script>
<script>
    var a = angular.module("app").value("appSettings", myApp);
</script>
```

and in your angular controller, the `appSettings` will be injected and you can use that and build the correct url to your other web api end points.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
var ctrl = function (appSettings,$http) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.baseUrl = appSettings.Urls.baseUrl;
    //build other urls using the base url now
    var getUGroupsUrl = vm.baseUrl + "api/Groups/GetGroups";
    // you can use getUGroupsUrl  now for your http calls.
    console.log(getUGroupsUrl);

   $http.get(getUGroupsUrl).then(function(response) {

       console.log(response.data);
   }

};
ctrl.inject=['$http'];
app.controller("ctrl", ctrl)
```

You may also consider moving your web api calls from your angular controller to [a data service](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#data-services) to keep things clean & keep concern separated.

Answer (score 0):

I found easy way to accomplish what I was looking for:

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: window.location.origin + '/api/Groups/GetGroups',
            dataType: "json",
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.groups = response.data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            alert("trouble..");
        });
    });
```

and the key is window.location.origin which returns protocol + host + port