# Deserialize JSON object into C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 webapp, on the client side, I have two JavaScript constructors

```
MyDate = function (y, m, d) {
    this.year = y;
    this.month = m;
    this.day = d;
}

Person = function (dateOfBirth, name) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    this.name = name;
}
```

And on a Razor view, I have the following function which constructs a `Person` object and post it to an Action method

```
saveThisPerson = function () {

    var dob = new MyDate(1980, 5, 19);

    var p = new Person(dob, 'Mike');

    var requestUri = "/MyProfile/SaveThisPerson";
    var req = JSON.stringify(p);

    $http.post(requestUri, req).success(function (data) {
        // yeas !! this person is saved!!   
    })
}
```

On the C# side, this is the `SaveThisPerson` method:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveThisPerson(Person person)
{
    // omitted
}
```

And these are two C# classes needed

```
public class Person
{
    public MyDate DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyDate
{
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public int Month { get; set; }

    public int Day { get; set; }
}
```

When I run it, the `SaveThisPerson` action method is called and the posted json is deserialized to a `Person` object with name field correctly populated (as "Mike"). But the `DateOfBirth` field has Year/Month/Day all equal to 0. What do I need to do to make the `DateOfBirth` field correctly deserialized? - in this case to Year = 1980, Month = 5, and Day = 19. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use DateTime instead?. I mean, DateOfBirth can be the DateTime property, you don't need a new class for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using angular `$http` service, you do not need to use `JSON.stringify`. angular will take care of all those.

```
var dob = new MyDate(1980, 5, 19);
var p = new Person(dob, 'Mike');

var requestUri = "@Url.Action("SaveThisPerson","MyProfile")";   

$http.post(requestUri, p)
    .then(function (data) {
       console.log(data.data);
       // yeas !! this person is saved!!   
    });
```

The above code uses `Url.Action` helper method to build the correct relative url to the `SaveThisPerson` action method. If your javascript code is not in the razor view, but in an external js file, you should build the relative url to the app root and pass it to your javascript code as explained  [in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600382/asp-mvc-angular-js-http-not-found/34600407#34600407)

Also, You should consider using the `DateTime` type in your DTO for the datetime instead of building your own custom class.

```
public class Person
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And angular/javascript code will be

```
var p = { Name="Scott" , DateOfBirth="12/26/2015" };
var requestUri = "@Url.Action("SaveThisPerson","MyProfile")";   

$http.post(requestUri, p)
    .then(function (data) {
       console.log(data.data);
       // yeas !! this person is saved!!   
    });
```

Comment: removing the var req = JSON.stringify(p); did the trick. Thanks. 

I shouldn't have used MyDate custom type in the example code. That created distraction to what I want to ask. My Bad.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of you code.

```
   $.post(requestUri, {person:req}, function (data) {
    // yeas !! this person is saved!!   
   });
```

In your javascript, Remove MyDate class and have dateOfBirth as a string in Person class.

Change your person class like this;

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

If you really need to have DateOfBirth as string, and want to be able to convert it in to a DateTime later, you may do this.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateOfBirth, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you still want to use MyDate class change your controller like this.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostComplexType(string person)
    {
        var oPerson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(person);
        return Json("success");
    }
```